# Has Sphero broken compatibility with Python SDKs when introducing Bolt?

Tags: python, sphero, bolt

So I have been researching Python SDKs for the Sphero over the past several days. Among those I found are `Kulka` and `SpheroPy`, though I found another which is 5 years old and hasn't been updated since then.

Neither the `Kulka` or `SpheroPy` implementations will connect to my `Sphero Bolt` though. It has been successfully paired with my Windows 10 PC, and has a unique identifier of "`c8:31:f5:7e:f4:30`". Each time I tell any of these APIS to connect to the `sphero`, they throw a `traceback` and tell me they can't connect because the connected party isn't responding.
  I've successfully connected `Sphero Bolt` to the `Sphero Edu` app on my phone.

However, I am blind, and the app is not screen reader friendly, so my preferred method of controlling it would be through an external API. Still, the fact that it connected to the `Sphero Edu` app + the fact that it paired to my PC show that its bluetooth capability is functional. I have looked around and, perhaps because no research has really been done into it, no one has offered a working solution to this and I'm perplexed myself.

Answer (score 1):

For Sphero Bolt, I think currently there are two options:

1. [pysphero](https://github.com/EnotYoyo/pysphero), which is a Python API that is supposed to be fully functional for Bolt.
2. [spherov2.js](https://github.com/igbopie/spherov2.js), which is a JavaScript API that seems to focus on Sphero mini, but probably works for Bolt as well.

Sphero the company seems to have crippled the programmability of these toys. These two libraries I listed seem to mimic the Sphero Edu Android app to function.

I don't have a Bolt, I only have a SPRK+, so I did not have a chance to test the libraries I just listed. But they both seem to be quite responsive in their Github issues sections. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to BOLT directly using BLE services, but you have to implement communication services yourself. However, you don't have to start completely from scratch. Find more resources by googling these GUIDs:
00010001-574f-4f20-5370-6865726f2121
00020001-574f-4f20-5370-6865726f2121